# Fingerprint enrollment Verifinger SDK (C#)

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I need to enroll fingerprint from fingerprint scanner (also recognize it in the future) from U.are.U 4500.
Currently I`m trying to develop C# Windows application using [Verifinger SDK](https://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html). I still can not understand how to enroll fingerprint using scanner. I also could not figure it out after looking to  [simple apps provided here](https://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html#megamatcher_verifinger_verilook_verieye_sdk_trial) and searching on the web.

If there is anyone who knows how to capture fingerprint, kindly explain it to me.

Below is the part of the code where as far as I understood scans fingerprint from scanner:

```
private async void ScanButtonClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_biometricClient.FingerScanner == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Please select a scanner from the list.");
        }
        else
        {
            EnableControls(true);
            lblQuality.Text = String.Empty;

            // Create a finger
            _subjectFinger = new NFinger();

            // Set Manual capturing mode if not automatic selected
            if (!chbScanAutomatically.Checked)
            {
                _subjectFinger.CaptureOptions = NBiometricCaptureOptions.Manual;
            }

            // Add finger to the subject and fingerView
            _subject = new NSubject();
            _subject.Fingers.Add(_subjectFinger);
            _subjectFinger.PropertyChanged += OnAttributesPropertyChanged;
            fingerView.Finger = _subjectFinger;
            fingerView.ShownImage = ShownImage.Original;

            // Begin capturing
            _biometricClient.FingersReturnBinarizedImage = true;
            NBiometricTask task = _biometricClient.CreateTask(NBiometricOperations.Capture | NBiometricOperations.CreateTemplate, _subject);
            var performedTask = await _biometricClient.PerformTaskAsync(task);
            OnEnrollCompleted(performedTask);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code posted should automatically read the image from the scanner.  The scanner should either by an ethernet device or a usb device.  So you should be able to see the scanner in Device Manager and the type of the scanner should be in the list of scanners.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your comment! So what it does after caputring finger?I think it has to return some value for me to save it into database right? If yes do you how it does it?

Comment: See following : https://www.bnl.gov/phobos/Detectors/Computing/Orant/doc/network.804/a48511/ch8.htm